# AWS Postgres RDS database connection to Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, amazon-rds

I have an existing spring boot application built using Gradle and i want this app to be connected to AWS RDS Postgres DB.  I could not find any useful links so far to achieve this. Can someone please point me to some helpful link to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can check :

1. Is your network allowing to connecting to the external AWS instances, like firewall. Make sure you are not blocked.
2. You to use a certificate to connect, make sure you have installed it properly.

Comment: i run the spring boot application via aws cloud9 so firewall or certificates are not an issue. I want the steps to connect to the DB

Comment: Okay, Its a standard DB connection procedure. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_CommonTasks.Connect.html might help